# Flutter : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) HTML

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried to insert my html text to display in my Flutter app. I've got some warning, but the result was good.

My Code:

```
final response = await http.get(
   Uri.parse(BaseUrl.apiBaseUrl + 'myapi'),
   headers: { HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer " + token });
      
final result = json.decode(response.body);
```

How I fix this warning?

> I/flutter ( 8104): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character
>
> 1. I/flutter ( 8104):  I/flutter ( 8104): ^ I/flutter (
>    8104): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
>    I/flutter ( 8104):  I/flutter ( 8104): ^

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on `final result = json.decode(response.body);`
In your response body, you are either getting a null or a non JSON format. That's why when your code is decoding it into JSON there is an exception.

Comment: i get response status 200 and i didn't get a null or not a json format.
I can call and then display it from my laravel API to Flutter, but I keep getting that error info.

Comment: @PremanTerminal if you not getting a JSON, then you should not be using json.decode

Comment: `if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = result['data'];
        print(data);
        if (data.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
...
judul = data['judul'].toString();
            body_portal = data['body_portal'].toString();
            created_at1 = Jiffy(data['created_at']).fromNow().toString();
            link = data['link'].toString();
            dokumenportal = data['dokumen_portal'].toString();
...

});
        }
      }`

Comment: I get a json dude  I can call and then display it from my laravel API to Flutter, but I keep getting that error info...

Comment: @PremanTerminal try `print(response.body)` and check if it is a JSON or not.

Answer (score 1):

My guess based on the info you've given is that `response.body` is not valid JSON. The warning thrown does match with it. Can you log out `response.body` before calling `json.decode()` on it and validate this theory?

Also, you're saying that you are trying to insert HTML - why is it being decoded from JSON? Maybe you can skip the decode altogether when you're only interested in the raw output of the `http.get()` query.

Comment: the reason why I got my html code format from json because i got it from API to display it on mobile-flutter.